# shell script: How to create a dictionary from the list?

Tags: bash

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
b=$(awk -F "[|]" '{print $1}' test.txt)
days=$(awk -F "[{}]"  '{print $1}' test.txt) #days
time=$(awk -F "[{}]"  '{print $2}' test.txt) #time
#count=`echo $d | wc -l`
#echo $count
declare -A arr
for i in $days;do
        echo $i
    for j in $time;
        echo $j
    done
done
```

### test.txt:

```
azureuser@disk-bkp:~$ cat test.txt
 Mo Tu We Th Fr {19:00 18:00 16:00 19:00 19:00}
```

> The below one is the output from the above code :

```
Mo
19:00
18:00
16:00
19:00
19:00
Tu
19:00
18:00
16:00
19:00
19:00
We
19:00
18:00
16:00
19:00
19:00
Th
19:00
18:00
16:00
19:00
19:00
Fr
19:00
18:00
16:00
19:00
19:00
```

> expected output is :

```
Mo
 19:00
Tu
18:00

We
16:00
Th
19:00

Fr
19:00
```

I wanted to create a key/value pairs based above lists and I need to get the **value** based on the **key**.
`$days` output is `Mo Tu We Th Fr` and `$time` is `19:00 23:00 16:00 23:00 15:00`. Expected Output is **Mo:19:00 Tu:23:00 We:16:00 Th:23:00 Fr:15:00**

Comment: Edit your question with additional info on how *text.txt* is organized.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use awk for the setting of the key/value array you need to change your input file to:

```
Mo 19:00
Tu 18:00
We 16:00
Th 19:00
Fr 19:00
```

Then

```
awk '{a[$1]=$2} END {for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' test.txt 

Tu 18:00
We 16:00
Fr 19:00
Mo 19:00
Th 19:00
```

a[] is the key/value array you want. But as you can see the order has changed by awk.
To prevent this we further change your input file to:

```
1Mo 19:00
2Tu 18:00
3We 16:00
4Th 19:00
5Fr 19:00
```

so we can restore the order using the first column later. Then

```
awk '{a[$1]=$2} END {for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' test.txt | sort -k1 | cut -c 2- | tr '\n' ' '
```

Which gives the output you want:

```
Mo 19:00 Tu 18:00 We 16:00 Th 19:00 Fr 19:00
```

But be aware that the keys in array a[] now contain the additional column which you may not want.

Comment: Hi Mr Elm, actually I'm appending output of  **tag=`curl -s -H Metadata:true --noproxy "*" "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance/compute/tagsList?api-version=2019-06-04"|  jq -r '.[]|select(.name == "auto_stop").value' | cut -d '' -f1 | sed 's/[][]//g' ` to test.txt

Comment: so from test.txt file contains **Mo Tu We Th Fr {19:00 18:00 16:00 19:00 19:00}**